# Generator help confused

Tags: electrical, generator, engine

[image]

Hey anyone help left side of the pik is one generator 
Geting uneven voltages without switching the contactor on 
Think its the avr card

But what really gets me is L1_E geting 2 v ?  Thats with the load on

But I switched generators over in a ats and the other generator on the right side of the picture all is healthy 
Anyone help out ? . Maybe the alternator windings  ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a home improvement question.

Comment: @isherwood 392v 3-phase wye is not a commercial voltage.  It's Eurostyle residential 230V.  Most houses get a single phase but nicer houses get all 3.

Comment: Sure, but is generator repair itself relevant?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your generator has an internal ground fault between winding L1 and earth.  It's not so bad when the generator is unloaded, but load just causes it to short dead.

Normally this would put it in a battle with the neutral-ground bond that would result in a breaker trip... but it looks like your neutral-ground bond is cheese.

Comment: So the generator its self has a ground fault with L1 . So the load side aint the issue

Comment: My way forward was check the alternator windings do a insulation resistance and continuity test . And check the avr card  and check neutral ground bonds .

Comment: A megger would be needed to check the windings to ground. A megger is a high voltage ohm meter , I would want to use 1000 v model but 500 v may show the problem.

Comment: Thankyou harper thats it fixed was a neutral from the alternator that snapped and wasent connected to the earth.

Comment: Dont understand why it would through of L1 on loads  if it was just a snapped neutral wire though ? Anyone?

Comment: Since you hadn't grounded it anywhere, it had to ground somewhere.